# ffmpeg Unrecognized option 'hls_enc'

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

Does anyone have a ffmpeg problem that Unrecognized option 'hls_enc'?

when I use ffmpeg to convert videos to hls with option 'hls_enc',followed the document: https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#Options-5
but throw error:Unrecognized option 'hls_enc'

Is it missing any configure options?

configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --yasmexe=/data/ffmpeg.src/_release/bin/yasm --prefix=/data/ffmpeg.src/_release --cc= --enable-static --disable-shared --enable-debug --extra-cflags='-I/data/ffmpeg.src/_release/include' --extra-ldflags='-L/data/ffmpeg.src/_release/lib -lm -ldl' --enable-postproc --enable-bzlib --enable-zlib --enable-parsers --enable-pthreads --enable-libx264 --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libfdk_aac --enable-libspeex --extra-libs=-lpthread --enable-encoders --enable-decoders --enable-avfilter --enable-muxers --enable-demuxers

Comment: Show your actual command and the complete console output. See the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) to see how to properly format your question.

Comment: That option was added two months ago. Is your source that recent?

Comment: @Mulvya yes,I download the leatest version of 3.3.2

Comment: @LordNeckbeard 
ffmpeg -y -i 99f1cda0ff1353188e9859f94ad3159f.mp4 -s 1280x720 -minrate 300K -maxrate 5000K -r 15  -vcodec libx264 -b:a 96K  -ar 44100 -acodec aac -bufsize 2000K -hls_time 5 -hls_list_size 0 -hls_playlist_type vod -hls_enc 1 -hls_segment_filename 95008515-2335-4BD7-A394-11F11AF39008/%d.ts -hls_base_url 95008515-2335-4BD7-A394-11F11AF39008/ 95008515-2335-4BD7-A394-11F11AF39008.m3u8

Comment: @LordNeckbeard I know how create keyinfo file,but I want ffmpeg create it automatic,that I do not need delete the keyinfo file after converted.

Comment: @riubin I meant that you should [edit] your question with the requested info (also you forgot the console output). Anyway, 3.3 branch is too old for this option. 3.3 was cut from master on 2017-04-02, but this option was added on 2017-04-14. Releases do not get backports of new features. Use code from the git master branch instead.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Thank you,solved!

Comment: @riubin Good. I'll make the comment as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 3.3 branch is too old for this option. 3.3 was cut from master on 2017-04-02, but this option was added on 2017-04-14. Releases do not get backports of new features. Compile using the code source from the git master branch instead. See "Get the Sources" on the [FFmpeg Download](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html) page.